# grid view search using dropdown list and text box filter?

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

Sir/madam now my problem is this that I want to filter the Grid View of a page using a Drop Down list and a text box.

I mean to say like we write a SQL such as:

```
Select  * from student where roll_no = 101;
```

Right,

Now I what that the column (`roll_no` in above statement) should be selected by the drop down list and the value (101 in the above statement) should be entered by the Text box.

In short I want to populate my grid view using Drop Down list and the value of text box by clicking a button..

For developing i am using dataset and table adapters.

Please, help me for this..

Answer (score 1):

I use a drop-down list (combo-box) and a textbox to filter my `DataGridView` the following way and I think this is what you are looking for.

First, populate your `DataGridView`. You state you are using a `DataSet` and `TableAdapters`. I am guessing that you are using a `BindingSource` to tie your Data to your `DataGridView`. If that is the case, then you can `Filter` your data via the `BindingSource`.

My set up is similar to this:

[image]

My combobox contains the fields that I want to use in my Filter and the textbox is the value that I will be applying. The values in the combobox are user-friendly names so they will understand which field they are filtering on.

The code to apply the filter is:

```
private void ApplyFilter()
{
     var filterEntered = FilterTextBox.Text.Trim().ToLower();

     MyBindingSource.RemoveFilter(); // remove previous filter

     string filterText = string.Empty;
     string filterComboText = string.Empty;

     switch (FilterComboBox.Text)
     {
         case "Profile":
            filterComboText = "TSProfile"; // column name in the query
            break;
         case "User Id":
            filterComboText = "TSUserId";
            break;
         case "Center":
            filterComboText = "TSCenter";
            break;
         case "Prefix":
            filterComboText = "TSPrefix";
            break;
     }

     filterComboText = filterComboText + " = '";

     filterText += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterComboText) ? string.Empty : filterComboText);
     filterText += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterEntered) ? filterEntered + "'" : string.Empty);

     MyBindingSource.Filter = filterText;
}
```

Basically what it is doing, is getting the text name of the combo-box and then the text in the textbox and applying the Filter to the BindingSource.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx) has an article on Filtering thats contains full sample code.

The one thing that I recommend is to provide the user with a way to easily remove the filter, I use a Remove Filter button.

Answer (score 0):

it would be helpful if you showed us a little code first..

you could try something like this tho:

in your codebehind, add items to your dropdownlist.

```
List<yourObject> list = new List<yourObject>();
foreach (yourObject i in list)
 {
  DropdownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("" i.name, "" + i.id));
 }
```

im just giving an example here, i.name could be the name of a certain student, i.id would be the id associated with that given student.

Make sure you have the autopostback attribute of your dropdownlist set to true, like this:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Then in the selected Index Changed event of your dropdownlist, do the following:

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
yourDataControl.DataSource = someMethod(Convert.toInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
yourDatacontrol.DataBind();
}
```

as i said, im not entirely sure what you're trying to do or how you're trying to do it. 
the way i'm describing, you dont need the textbox to enter a certain value, by selecting an item in the dropdownlist you wil automatically get a value: in this case the ID associated with the selected item in the dropdownlist.

Comment: Sir/Madam, ofcourse i have already filled up my drop down list.bt actual problem is this that i want to filter the database using a non key attribute